# Recuperar informação do firebase e colocar num textformfield flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firestore

Estou tentando recuperar informação do meu banco de dados, porém quando eu tento utilizar os dados que recuperei nos *widgets*, tenho um erro dizendo que minhas *strings* (onde estou colocando o conteúdo do *firebase*) estão vazias.

O que estou tentando fazer é uma tela onde consigo editar informações; porém, no meu *TextFormField*, gostaria que elas fossem previamente carregadas para que o usuário não precisasse digitar tudo novamente.

```
class DetalhesPendencia extends StatelessWidget {


  Pendencia pendencia;

  DetalhesPendencia(this.pendencia);
  TextEditingController _controllerDescricao = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controllerEstagio = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controllerResponsavel = TextEditingController();



  _carregarInformacoes () async {

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await db.collection("barcos")
    .doc(pendencia.embarcacao)
    .collection("pendencias")
    .doc(pendencia.id)
    .get();

    var dados = snapshot.data();
    String preDescricao = dados["descricao"];
    String preEstagio = dados["estagio"];
    String preResponsavel = dados ["responsavel"];

  }


  _salvarPendencia () async {

    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("dd / MM / yyyy: hh:mm");

    String descricao = _controllerDescricao.text;
    String estagio = _controllerEstagio.text;
    String responsavel = _controllerResponsavel.text;
    String data = dateFormat.format(DateTime.now());

    pendencia.descricao = descricao;
    pendencia.estagio = estagio;
    pendencia.responsavel = responsavel;
    pendencia.data = data;

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    db.collection("barcos")
        .doc(pendencia.embarcacao)
        .collection("pendencias")
        .doc(pendencia.id)
        .set(pendencia.toMap());

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    _carregarInformacoes();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar (
        title: Text ("Pendência"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        foregroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: () {
          _salvarPendencia();
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column (
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text (pendencia.item
                ,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                child: Divider(),
              ),
              Text ("Descrição:"
                ,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(

                  initialValue: preDescricao;
                  controller: _controllerDescricao,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32, 16, 32, 16),
                    hintText: "descricao",
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6))),
              ),
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você chama a função de recuperar no initState?
Pode levar uma pequena fração de segundos até que os dados sejam recuperados, devido a isso talvez seja interessante você salvar os dados que deseja recuperar diretamente no controller ( _controller.text = preDescricao). Assim o texto será alterado independente se você chamar setState ou não. Porque passando para initialValie do textForm o valor que será carregado é o valor que a string possui no momento da criação do Widget.